# Discriminator's and Generator's losses training a cGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm a little confused about the Generator's and Discriminator's losses while training a cGAN. I am aware that a stable GAN is one where the Discriminator's loss reaches 0.5. I know that we can read off a failure mode in training a GAN when the Disc loss drops to zero or close to zero and the genrator's loss keep on increasing.

I am training a cGAN and I found two different results, one where this failure mode is evidently but the result generated is very good anyway. And another one where the loss of the Discriminator stabilizes in 1.38 and the Generators in 0.69. I read in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332991/how-to-interpret-the-following-gan-training-losses?rq=1) that these two values are "Ideal situation" but I really don't see why. Examples in the figures:

[image]
[image]

Is this ok? I mean, is it ok to have the Generator's loss below that one of the Discriminator at the end of the training?

The second issue is with the failure. Altough the Loss looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The final result is **very good**:

[image]

I mean, when the training ended the value of Fidelity was 0.9998 (1.000 is the best possible) and the output was really close to the target. What can explain this? With such a big loss for the Generator and such a low loss for the Discriminator (it was zero) shouldn't this GAN output just random noise?

I also have a result like the following:

[image]

where the loss of both Disc and Gen are stable and approximately constant during all training. Is it a problem?